Why is browser-error returned while verifying recaptcha v3?
I want to use recaptcha v3 in my website but it returns browser-error code while verifying recatcha token. The site-key and secret-key are set correctly for sure.
The full response is:
{'success': False, 'error-codes': ['browser-error']}
The url I send the the request:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
The request body:
{'response': <recaptcha token>, 'secret': <secret>'}
I expect to retrive the score of the recapthca token instead of browser-error.

I have just set the wrong domain... I changed the settings to accept tokens from every origin.
